# Jupyterlab load model fromJSON issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am developing notebook syncronization mechanism using websockets between jupyterlab users editing same notebook, here is what i am doing:

```
// having notebook instance as a NotebookPanel
// I am merging UI cell data and server (other's edited) cell data
// `updatedModel` contains merged cells from server and from user's current changes in the notebook.
notebook.context.model.fromJSON(updatedModel.content);
```

I am facing following issue:

[image: console output]

and cell actions disappear.

[image]

did anyone have this issue and came up with a solution to properly load notebook from a json?

Jupyterlab Version `3.5.0`

Reproduction Code:

```js
import {JupyterFrontEnd, JupyterFrontEndPlugin} from "@jupyterlab/application";
import {INotebookTracker, NotebookPanel, NotebookTracker} from "@jupyterlab/notebook";

const testCopyModelFromJSON = (notebookTracker: NotebookTracker) => {
    notebookTracker.widgetAdded.connect((tracker: NotebookTracker, panel: NotebookPanel) => {
        let notebook = panel.content;
        const notebookModel = notebook.model;
        if (!notebookModel) {
            return;
        }
        const model = notebookModel.toJSON();
        notebookModel.fromJSON(model);
    });
}

const plugin: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
    id: 'nbsync-extension:plugin',
    autoStart: true,
    requires: [INotebookTracker],
    activate: (app: JupyterFrontEnd, notebookTracker: NotebookTracker) => {
        console.info('nbsync-extension started');
        app.started
            .then(() => {
                testCopyModelFromJSON(notebookTracker);
            });
        app.restored
            .then(() => {
                testCopyModelFromJSON(notebookTracker);
            });
    }
};

export default plugin;
```

dependencies:

```
"@jupyterlab/application": "^3.5.0",
"@jupyterlab/notebook": "^3.5.0"
```

Comment: I saw this error but not in this context: there is a bug with cell toolbar, see https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/13728, but this could be unrelated to the problem you are facing.

Comment: As for the issue you are trying to solve at large, probably more code (a reproducible example) would be needed.

Comment: included reproduction code

Comment: Thanks I cen reproduce this. I opened a PR which may solve the underlying cell toolbar issue, let's see how this goes.